# Filter search filter data showing from Api using provider

Tags: flutter, api, dart, search

how to implement search filter with API using provider? i have post Api when user hit Api it send back data to the user

My api

```
Future<List<Searchmodel>>Search(String keyword) async {
    final response=await http.post(Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/library/search'),body: {
      'Keyword': keyword,
    });
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      final json=response.body..toString().replaceAll("\n","");
      var data=jsonDecode(json);
      final Iterable fetch = data["success"];
      return fetch.map((category) => Searchmodel.fromJson(category)).toList();
    }else{
      throw Exception("Unable to perform request!");
    }

}

//model class

class Searchmodel {
  Searchmodel({
      required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.file,
      required this.categoryId,
      required this.subcategoryId,
      required this.userId,
      required this.status,
      required this.createdAt,
      required this.updatedAt,});

  Searchmodel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    file = json['file'];
    categoryId = json['category_id'];
    subcategoryId = json['subcategory_id'];
    userId = json['user_id'];
    status = json['status'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? file;
  int? categoryId;
  int? subcategoryId;
  String? userId;
  String? status;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['file'] = file;
    map['category_id'] = categoryId;
    map['subcategory_id'] = subcategoryId;
    map['user_id'] = userId;
    map['status'] = status;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return map;
  }

}

//UI


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:livinghopegeetzaboor/Statemanagment/Library/LibraryProvider.dart';
import 'package:livinghopegeetzaboor/constant/AppColor.dart';
import 'package:livinghopegeetzaboor/sacreen/Geet/Geetsubcategory.dart';
import 'package:livinghopegeetzaboor/services/Services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}


class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  


    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                 Container(
                   height: 100,
                     width: 100,
                     child: Image.asset('images/logo.png')

                 ),
                  // Note: Same code is applied for the TextFormField as well
                  // Note: Same code is applied for the TextFormField as well
                  // Note: Same code is applied for the TextFormField as well
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                    child:Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        color: AppColor.color,
                      ),
                      height: 80,

                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                  size: 40,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width:2),

                                  ),
                                  filled: true, //<-- SEE HERE
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Search for any songs',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 3,),
                            // Container(
                            //   height: 59,
                            //   width: 59,
                            //   color:Colors.white,
                            //   constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                            //
                            //   ),
                            //   // child: Icon(
                            //   //   Icons.search_sharp,
                            //   //   size: 40,
                            //   //   color: AppColor.color,
                            //   // ),
                            // )

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),




                             Consumer<LibraryProvider>(
                               builder:(BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
                                 if(value.isloading){
                                   return CircularProgressIndicator(
                                     color: AppColor.color,
                                   );
                                 }else{
                                   return GridView.builder(
                                     itemCount:value.library.length,
                                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                     shrinkWrap: true,
                                     gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                         crossAxisCount: 3,
                                         crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                                         mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
                                     ),
                                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                         var subtitle=value.library[index].name2;
                                       return Padding(
                                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                         child: Material(
                                           color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                                           child: InkWell(
                                             splashColor: Colors.orange,

                                             child: Container(
                                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                 color: Colors.black,
                                               ),

                                               //color: Colors.black,
                                               height:200,
                                               width: 200,
                                               child: Column(
                                                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 children: [
                                               Padding(

                                                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                 child: Center(
                                                     child: Text(value.library[index]!.name.toString(),style: TextStyle(
                                                         color: Colors.white,
                                                         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                         fontSize: 18
                                                     ),),
                                                 ),
                                               ),

                                                   SizedBox(height: 4,),
                                                   Padding(
                                                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                                     child: Center(
                                                       child: subtitle!=null ? Text(value.library[index].name2.toString(),style: TextStyle(
                                                           color: Colors.white,
                                                           fontSize: 12
                                                       ),):Text('',style: TextStyle(
                                                           color: Colors.white,
                                                           fontSize: 12
                                                       ),)
                                                     ),
                                                   ),

                                                 ],


                                               ),
                                             ),
                                             onTap: (){

                                               Navigator.push(
                                                 context,
                                                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Geetsubcategory(id: value.library[index].id,)),

                                               );
                                             },
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       );
                                     },
                                   );
                                 }


                               },

                             )




                ],


              ),
              // your main content
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){

    Provider.of<LibraryProvider>(context,listen: false).fetchlibary();


     // Add Your Code here.

   });
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your `LibraryProvider` code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the api call from inside your provider function.

Like this

```
class SearchProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  List<dynamic>? _items;
  List<dynamic>? get items => _items;

  void searchItems(String val) async {
    _items = await ApiCall.search(val);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

You can create a common object of provider on the page to use throughout your page like this.

```
  SearchProvider _provider = SearchProvider();
```

and use it like this in your provider and consumer on the same page

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchProvider>(
  create: (_) => _provider,
  child: Column(
     children: [
        ...  // other code 
        Consumer<SearchProvider>(
          builder: (context, provider, w) {
            if (provider.items != null && provider.items!.isNotEmpty) {
               return SearchList(list: provider.items);
            }
            return const Center(child: Text("Nothing found"));
          },
        ),
     ]),
   ),
```

Then setup one `TextField` to type & fire search query. You can setup `onSubmitted` callback of the `Textfield` to call your provider method.

```
TextField(
  onSubmitted: (val) {
    if(val.length > 0){
      _provider.searchItems(val);
    }
    else {
      _provider.getAll();
    }
  },
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
  labelText: 'Search', 
  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
),
```

Using this code will call the provider method when you press enter after typing some query in TextField. That provider method will then call the api & store the response in a List then call `notifyListeners()` from that method to notify all the consumers. Those consumer then try to read the list & create a listview if they find data in the list.

Here is an example of full working code:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=a5950f2da95d58e32dc9176433d9bcb3

I have also added the onload list which can be filtered from api itself & it user delete search query it will again call the full list api for data.

Hope this will help you understand things better using provider.